# Call a Query from a Query in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a pipeline of queries I need to process sequentially, each of which is fairly complex. It is not efficient to run them from an editor or command line, wait for it to finish, type the next, etc. especially given some can take hours to finish.

Currently I just make one huge .sql (hich I run from editor) or .txt file (which I run from command line) with all my queries semi-colon delimited which is super-hard to edit and keep track of (not to mention I use parts of the queries in other places and would like any edits to update globally).

I can't find any visual tool to allow me to simply connect query "nodes" but wonder if there is anyway in a query to call another query by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Stored Procedures and Functions. You can also define a View and store it, then treat it as a table. A function can run a query and return a single result, while a stored procedure can have a result set, although you typically need to put results into a temporary table if you are going to use it from another stored procedure.